# Is it mandatory for service to have sidecar enabled for istio rate limits to work?

Tags: istio

When I perform enabling rate limits task memory quota, the rate limits do not work.

I am following the ratelimit doc as it. Except, one thing I can see different from the demo setup is that my service as sidecar disabled.

Running istio on kubernetes
Release istio 1.2.5

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: quotahandler
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledAdapter: memquota
  params:
    quotas:
    - name: requestcountquota.instance.istio-system
      maxAmount: 2
      validDuration: 1s
      # The first matching override is applied.
      # A requestcount instance is checked against override dimensions.
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: requestcountquota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledTemplate: quota
  params:
    dimensions:
      source: request.headers["x-forwarded-for"] | "unknown"
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpec
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  rules:
  - quotas:
    - charge: 1
      quota: requestcountquota
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpecBinding
metadata:
  name: request-count
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  quotaSpecs:
  - name: request-count
    namespace: istio-system
  services:
  - name: my-service
    namespace: default
  #- service: '*'  # Uncomment this to bind *all* services to request-count

---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  # quota only applies if you are not logged in.
  # match: match(request.headers["cookie"], "user=*") == false
  actions:
  - handler: quotahandler
    instances:
    - requestcountquota
```

Also tried restarting pilot and mixer and found no errors in logs.

Is it mandatory that pods of `my-service` to have istio sidecar running for rate limiting to work? (we do have virtualservice for routing, but no sidecar because want to allow external calls from the application)

Comment: The sidecars are necessary to enable pretty much any istio functionality , so yes it is necessary. For enabling calls from your app to outside the mesh, you can change egress policy or create service entries, this is all detailed here: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/

Comment: Hi, Does comment from @Joel answers Your question? Also do You have `VirtualService` and `GateWay` configured? If Your service is not sidecar injected by istio envoy the istio is not used for network communication and rate limiting cannot be applied.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, have Gateway and VirtualService for ingress. Let me have egress and sidecar as well. Makes sense.

Comment: I have made community wiki answer to add visibility to this information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the service needs to be envoy sidecar injected to allow rate limits.

Like Joel, mentioned in comment:

> The sidecars are necessary to enable pretty much any istio functionality , so yes it is necessary. For enabling calls from your app to outside the mesh, you can change egress policy or create service entries, this is all detailed here: [istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control](http://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control)

And mine:

> If Your service is not sidecar injected by istio envoy the istio is not used for network communication and rate limiting cannot be applied.

According to [istio](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#why-use-istio) documentation:

> Istio makes it easy to create a network of deployed services with load
>   balancing, service-to-service authentication, monitoring, and more,
>   with 
>   [few](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-context-propagation)
>   or no code changes in service code. You add Istio support to services
>   by deploying a special sidecar proxy throughout your environment that
>   intercepts all network communication between microservices, then
>   configure and manage Istio using its control plane functionality,
>   which includes:
>
> - Automatic load balancing for HTTP, gRPC, WebSocket, and TCP traffic.
> - Fine-grained control of traffic behavior with rich routing rules, retries, failovers, and fault injection.
> - A pluggable policy layer and configuration API supporting access controls, rate limits and quotas.
> - Automatic metrics, logs, and traces for all traffic within a cluster, including cluster ingress and egress.
> - Secure service-to-service communication in a cluster with strong identity-based authentication and authorization.
>
> Istio is designed for extensibility and meets diverse deployment
>   needs.